# Using a stack to build an expression tree

Tags: c++, stack, expression-trees

I'm attempting to write an expression tree function that takes in a character array expression and outputs the prefix, infix and postfix version. I have written this code and it doesn't throw any errors, but when run the calculated values don't print out. I've tried to debug the function but still cannot come up with a solution. Is anyone able to give me any tips about what I'm doing wrong with this?

```
void Expression_Tree::build_expression_tree(char input[], int size)
{
    ETNode *temp, *t1, *t2;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(!(i == '+' || i == '-' || i == '*' || i == '/' || i == '^')) {
            temp = new ETNode;
            temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
            temp->input = i;

            tree_stack.push(temp);
        }
        else {
            temp = new ETNode;
            temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
            temp->input = i;

            t1 = tree_stack.top();
            tree_stack.pop();
            t2 = tree_stack.top();
            tree_stack.pop();

            temp->right = t1;
            temp->left = t2;

            tree_stack.push(temp);
        }
    }

    temp = tree_stack.top();
    tree_stack.pop();
}
```

I've just included the build_expression_tree function, if there is nothing deemed wrong with this then it mustn't be linking to my inorder, preorder and postorder functions properly. Thanks!

Comment: The normal way in C++ is to use a constructor to initialize members (here: `ETNode`), not letting the user code do the initialization.

Comment: @stefaanv I have an ETNode class also

Comment: So, why are you setting the left and right pointers to NULL in the user code?

Comment: @stefaanv to read the input into new nodes?

Comment: Okay, I might be a bit too blunt, but reading your replies, I assume that you don't know what a constructor is, so you have no clue what I'm talking about.  Fair enough.

Comment: @stefaanv I understand what a constructor is, I've just tried this code a whole lot of ways with not a lot of clue as to how clearly. All I know is that I have to read the input into new nodes and that was the only way I could think of to make new nodes that would at least compile. :/

Comment: Making it compile is not enough.  Do you have some kind of plan, like a drawing how the tree should look like and how you would use it? or how you would do it by hand?

Comment: @stefaanv Yes, I have the steps mapped out and I've drawn the tree and what each result should be. I just can't get the code to work.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a copy-paste error, but you're using `i` as if it was a `char`.

I guess you want to use `input[i]` instead, at least in your `if` statement.

Comment: I did try that and it threw a segmentation fault

Comment: @user6276841: then maybe you should check at what you pass to the function.

Comment: This is the related code from my tester file that is being passed is:

`char input[] = {'2', '+', '(', '3', '*', '(', '2', '+', '2', ')', ')', '+', '5'};
int size = sizeof(input)/sizeof(char);

Expression_Tree a;
a.build_expression_tree(input, size);`

Comment: @user6276841 I think `sizeof(input)` gives you the number of elements of `input`, so you don't have to divide by `sizeof(char)`. Can you please check that the `size` value is correct?  If it's not that, can you find the exact line that segfaulted? If you can't debug, add some `printf` to see where your code goes.

Comment: @Gwen I attempted to debug, but the debugger just threw a large amount of 'multiple definition of' errors that I've never received before.

Comment: Can you add the following code at the beginning of your function and give us the result (sorry for the bad formatting)? `cerr << "size=" << size << endl; for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { cerr << "i=" << i<< endl; cerr << "input[i]=" << input[i]<< endl; }`

Comment: Based on your input, which is 'infix', your code, which is postfix, will already `top()` and `pop()` the tree while it only contains 1 number.  You just need to feed '2' and '+' to build function to see this.

Comment: @Gwen The result looks how it should: size=13
i=0
input[i]=2
i=1
input[i]=+
i=2
input[i]=(
i=3
input[i]=3
i=4
input[i]=*
i=5
input[i]=(
i=6
input[i]=2
i=7
input[i]=+
i=8
input[i]=2
i=9
input[i]=)
i=10
input[i]=)
i=11
input[i]=+
i=12
input[i]=5

Comment: @user6276841 Ok. What happens is that when you use `i`in your if statement, you always go through the first branch. That's why your code runs without crash, but doesn't do what you want. When you use the correct condition with `input[i]`, you sometimes go in the second branch where your code crashes due to the reason pointed by stefaanv. You should manually execute your code step-by-step, to see if it does what you want it to do, and where it is wrong (Hint: poping an empty stack raises an exception).

Comment: @Gwen I really appreciate your explanations. I've tried to add an else if for if the stack is empty, add the new node. Am I way off?

Comment: @user6276841 It may run without crashes, but it won't work. What I wanted you to see is that the code you built will not do what you want, unless you do several modifications. I suggest you to restart from scratch, after reading explanations about parsing this type of expressions (see [this](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/java/SimpleParser/SimpleParser.html) for example).

Comment: @Gwen you are correct, it compiles but doesn't work at all. I realise now I've accidentally been coding it for postfix to infix. Swell. Thanks for the help but